# Creating a column in a data.table for every value in a vector

Tags: r, data.table

I want to add the dates in a vector to an existing data table. Each date in the vector should be entered in a different column. I am trying to do this for a vector containing any number of dates - so basically I want generic code for a vector of length n. I do this the following way:

```
someDates  <- c(as.Date('2019-1-31'), as.Date('2019-3-30'))
newColumns <- paste0('col', 1:length(someDates))

date_column <- c(as.Date('2018-12-31'), as.Date('2018-11-30'), as.Date('2017-09-30'), as.Date('2016-01-30'))
some_column <- letters[1:4]

DT <- data.table(date_column, some_column)

DT[, (newColumns) := as.data.table(matrix(rep(someDates, each = nrow(DT)), nr = nrow(DT)))]
DT[, (newColumns) := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols = newColumns]
```

I don't find the using of the function `matrix` in the one but last step very beautiful - i also don't like the fact that I have to convert to date afterwards. Can I obtain the same result in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `as.list`

```
library(data.table)

DT[, (newColumns) := as.list(someDates)]

DT
#   date_column some_column       col1       col2
#1:  2018-12-31           a 2019-01-31 2019-03-30
#2:  2018-11-30           b 2019-01-31 2019-03-30
#3:  2017-09-30           c 2019-01-31 2019-03-30
#4:  2016-01-30           d 2019-01-31 2019-03-30
```

check `str(DT)` to see that the new columns are of class `Date`.

```
str(DT)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ date_column: Date, format: "2018-12-31" "2018-11-30" "2017-09-30" "2016-01-30"
# $ some_column: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d"
# $ col1       : Date, format: "2019-01-31" "2019-01-31" "2019-01-31" "2019-01-31"
# $ col2       : Date, format: "2019-03-30" "2019-03-30" "2019-03-30" "2019-03-30"
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak Shah. I had tried `list()` but that did not work because it stores the vector as a whole in the list rather than the elements of the vector as different objects in the list as `as.list()` does.